# how to process 3d models in blend4web

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine, constraints, blend-files, blend4web

well I want to implement on click changes in my blender model through html and blend4web.. kind of like dress up games where object changes on click.. Can we do that using blend4web web player?
please give the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in the Web Player by leveraging the Logic Editor.
See the example 
https://www.blend4web.com/apps/webplayer/webplayer.html?load=../../assets/interactivity/inherit_material.json
The corresponding source Blender file can be found in the free SDK.